# Untar single file to desired name

Tags: tar

When I `tar` a single file, I can give the `tar` file a desired name:

```
$ tar -cvfj A B
```

I would like to do the same when I untar a single file.

```
$ tar -xvjf A tmp
```

(ie. extract `A` into `tmp`).

I was trying to do this using `mv`:

```
$ tar -xvjf $1 | mv $1 tmp
```

That didn't work. `$1` can be an arbitrary name, but the `tar` files will always be a single file, no folders (this is guaranteed).

Comment: Are you just using `tar` for compression? If so, don't do that; just use the compression program directly (`bzip2` in your case)

Comment: @Fox yes, I am. What difference does it make?

Comment: If your local tar implementation does not create a file named `j` in your first example, it is broken.

Comment: Use `-C` : `tar -xvjf $1 -C tmp`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you seem to be using `tar` with `bzip2` compression as a way of just compressing a single file, you may want to consider using `bzip2` directly:

To compress a file (creates `filename.bz2`, deletes `filename`):

```
bzip2 filename
```

To decompress a file (creates `filename`, deletes `filename.bz2`):

```
bunzip2 filename.bz2
```

To compress to a specific filename (creates `newfilename.bz2`, keeps `filename`):

```
bzip2 -c filename >newfilename.bz2
```

To decompress to a specific filename (creates `newfilename`, keeps `filename.bz2`):

```
bunzip2 -c filename.bz2 >newfilename
```

See also the manual for `bzip2` on your system (`man bzip2`).

Comment: I like this solution. However, there is a file that has spaces. How can my bash script handle this? `./decomp "blah blah blah.bz2"` gets all messed up. When I used `bunzip2` directly, it's all good.

Comment: @SpentDeath Make sure that you double quote the variable expansion in your script.

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: @SpentDeath That means that rather than `$1`, you'd use `"$1"` so that your arguments don't get split

Answer (score 7):

Here is one solution:

```
tar -xjOf my.tar > out
```

This uses the `-O` option of tar

> `-O, --to-stdout`: extract files to standard output

and redirects standard output to a file called `out`.  If the archive has more than one file, `out` will be all of the files in the archive concatenated.

You should probably just be using `bzip2` directly, as during compression it will not store a file tree.  Instead, it will simply store the data within the file.

Comment: Caveat of this approach is you do not preserve metadata like permissions and symlinks.